# HTML not showing in App built with Eclipse and Phonegap

Tags: android, eclipse, html, cordova

I have followed the "Getting started with PhoneGap in Eclipse for Android" tutorial found here: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/getting-started-with-phonegap-in-eclipse-for-android.html following the steps exactly as it says (although there are now some differences based on the date this article was originally posted).

My problem is whenever I "Run As > Android Application" to test the "app" I'm just getting a blank white screen on the Android device. I've tested the index.html in a desktop web browser and it's showing up correctly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I resolved this by following this helpful tutorial:

http://codingsquare.blogspot.in/2013/08/creating-cordova-3-android-project.html